# How to automatically change DNS nameserver

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, dhcp

My ISP's DNS server has problems resolving lots of important websites like google, github, gmail etc. As a hack I manually edited the /etc/resolv.conf file to Google's 8.8.8.8.
But the changed file remodifies to my ISP's DNS service when there's a network change.
How do I automatically set /etc/resolv.conf to Google's DNS in the event of a network change and when I restart my computer using bash scripting.

I'm new to scripting on Linux. I'd need pointers on how to go about writing a script for this.
Thanks.

Comment: The solution may vary based on your distro/network management setup. Could you tell us what distro you're using?

Comment: I use an Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

Comment: Please refer to this answer on AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/63163

Comment: delete the `/etc/resolv.conf` link and create a static file with the nameservers of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/resolv.conf` file is usually managed by your network manager.

You can force your network manager to use specific DNS server.

For example, if you have Gnome, then in `gnome-control-center` you can do this:

[image]

The procedure will be similar for others network managers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

[image]

then change it

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

for the love of God, do not use google dns server. use cloudflare server

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

then

```
sudo chattr -a /etc/resolv.conf
sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
```

now check the status:

mousepad /etc/resolv.conf // or use leafpad

[image]

Now it is readonly